# Как ограничить DDoS-атаки средствами Lighttpd?

Tags: ddos, lighttpd

Понятно, что средствами веб-сеовера атаки не отразить, но какие модули и их настройки рекомендованы для снижения воздействия атаки?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для Lighttpd можно использовать модули защиты, например mod_evasive или/и mod_security.

Всё это базовые фильтры которые помогут отсеять мелкие ддос, но от крупных всё же лучше использовать даже бесплатные решения от cloudflare например.